# Query Studio Error- conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value " to data type int

Tags: marketing-cloud

The below query is getting the above error when I tried to run in Query Studio.
Also, the datatype of target and source DEs are same.

```
SELECT
    ea.SendId as SendId,
    ea.SendDate as SendDate,
    ea.Clicks as Clicks,
    ea.ClickedDate as ClickedDate,
    ea.Opens as Opens,
    ea.OpenedDate as OpenedDate,
    ea.BouncedDate as BouncedDate,
    ea.Channel as Channel,
    ea.Bounces as Bounces,
    ea.SendBatch as SendBatch,
    ea.SuperMessages as SuperMessages,
    ea.Autonumber as Autonumber,
    ea.ContactId as ContactId,
    ea.BusinessUnitName as BusinessUnitName,
    ea.BusinessUnit as BusinessUnit,
    ea.EmailSubject as EmailSubject,
    ea.MessageText as MessageText,
    jdsms.JourneyName as JourneyName,
    jdsms.JourneyID as JourneyID,
    jdsms.VersionNumber as VersionNumber,
    jdsms.SMSActivityName as ActivityName,
    jdsms.SendTime as SendTime,
    NULL as EmailAddress,
    jdsms.ContactKey as ContactKey,
    jdsms.JobID as JobID,
    NULL as ListID,
    NULL as BatchID,
    jdsms.MarketName as MarketName,
    jdsms.TemplateName as TemplateName,
    jdsms.MobileNumber as MobileNumber,
    jdsms.MessageID as MessageID,
    jdsms.GroupID as GroupID,
    NULL as AppID,
    NULL as SocialID,
    NULL as MessageType,
    NULL as Status,
    NULL as MessageToken
FROM 
    DE1 as ea
JOIN 
    DE2 as jdsms
ON 
    ea.ContactId = jdsms.ContactKey
WHERE
    ea.SendDate > DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), -5)
AND
    ea.BusinessUnit NOT IN (7299332, 7310492, 7317061, 7313779) 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ea.SendId as SendId,
    ea.SendDate as SendDate,
    ea.Clicks as Clicks,
    ea.ClickedDate as ClickedDate,
    ea.Opens as Opens,
    ea.OpenedDate as OpenedDate,
    ea.BouncedDate as BouncedDate,
    ea.Channel as Channel,
    ea.Bounces as Bounces,
    ea.SendBatch as SendBatch,
    ea.SuperMessages as SuperMessages,
    ea.Autonumber as Autonumber,
    ea.ContactId as ContactId,
    ea.BusinessUnitName as BusinessUnitName,
    ea.BusinessUnit as BusinessUnit,
    ea.EmailSubject as EmailSubject,
    ea.MessageText as MessageText,
    jdemail.JourneyName as JourneyName,
    jdemail.JourneyID as JourneyID,
    jdemail.VersionNumber as VersionNumber,
    jdemail.EmailActivityName as ActivityName,
    jdemail.SendTime as SendTime,
    jdemail.EmailAddress as EmailAddress,
    jdemail.ContactKey as ContactKey,
    jdemail.JobID as JobID,
    jdemail.ListID as ListID,
    jdemail.BatchID as BatchID,
    jdemail.MarketName as MarketName,
    jdemail.TemplateName as TemplateName,
    NULL as MobileNumber,
    NULL as MessageID,
    NULL as GroupID,
    NULL as AppID,
    NULL as SocialID,
    NULL as MessageType,
    NULL as Status,
    NULL as MessageToken
FROM 
    DE1 as ea
JOIN 
    DE3 as jdemail
ON 
    ea.ContactId = jdemail.ContactId
WHERE
    ea.SendDate > DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), -5)
AND
    ea.BusinessUnit NOT IN (7299332, 7310492, 7317061, 7313779)

UNION ALL
SELECT
    ea.SendId as SendId,
    ea.SendDate as SendDate,
    ea.Clicks as Clicks,
    ea.ClickedDate as ClickedDate,
    ea.Opens as Opens,
    ea.OpenedDate as OpenedDate,
    ea.BouncedDate as BouncedDate,
    ea.Channel as Channel,
    ea.Bounces as Bounces,
    ea.SendBatch as SendBatch,
    ea.SuperMessages as SuperMessages,
    ea.Autonumber as Autonumber,
    ea.ContactId as ContactId,
    ea.BusinessUnitName as BusinessUnitName,
    ea.BusinessUnit as BusinessUnit,
    ea.EmailSubject as EmailSubject,
    ea.MessageText as MessageText,
    NULL as JourneyName,
    jdsocial.JourneyID as JourneyID,
    NULL as VersionNumber,
    NULL as ActivityName,
    jdsocial.Date as SendTime,
    NULL as EmailAddress,
    NULL as ContactKey,
    NULL as JobID,
    NULL as ListID,
    NULL as BatchID,
    NULL as MarketName,
    NULL as TemplateName,
    NULL as MobileNumber,
    NULL as MessageID,
    NULL as GroupID,
    jdsocial.AppID as AppID,
    jdsocial.SocialID as SocialID,
    jdsocial.MessageType as MessageType,
    jdsocial.Status as Status,
    jdsocial.MessageToken as MessageToken
FROM 
    DE1 as ea
JOIN 
    DE4 as jdsocial
ON 
    ea.ContactId = jdsocial.ContactId
WHERE
    ea.SendDate > DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), -5)
AND
    ea.BusinessUnit NOT IN (7299332, 7310492, 7317061, 7313779)
```

Comment: I would recommend running this in automation studio

Answer (score 0):

I get this unjustified error a lot in Query Studio.
It looks like you have a lot of fields you are selecting. I would encourage an actual SQL activity in the automation studio given how large that query is.

But nonetheless, try using the `CAST( AS CHAR)`, e.g. `CAST(ea.BusinessUnitName  AS CHAR)`

That works for me.